# Unable to send Array to correct destination processor in MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, processor, hpc

I am trying to send an array to the different processors in the hypercube architecture. The problem is that it either doesn't send to all the processors or it sends to wrong processor. When I try to send a single integer it works correctly.

Here is the code:

```
void hypercube(int d,int my_id,int X[]){
  mask = (int)pow((double)2,d)-1;
 for(i = d-1;i>=0;i--){
        //printf("before xor mask is %d and power is %d\n",mask,(int)pow((double)2,i));
        mask = xor(mask,(int)pow((double)2,i));
        //printf("After xor rank is %d and mask is %d\n",rank,mask);
        if(and(my_id, mask) == 0){
                if(and(my_id,(int) pow((double)2,i)) == 0){
                        dest = xor(my_id,(int) pow((double)2,i));
                        printf("rank %d destination %d\n",rank,dest);
                        MPI_Send(&X,8,MPI_INT,dest,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);;
                        //MPI_Send(&X,1,MPI_INT,dest,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        //printf("After sending from rank %d and destination is %d\n",my_id,dest);
                }
                else{
                        //printf("going to receive in a sec...\n");
                        source = xor(my_id,(int)pow((double)2,i));
                        MPI_Recv(&X,8,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                        //MPI_Recv(&X,1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                        //printf("in rank %d with data %d\n",rank,X);

                }
        }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){


  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);


  if(rank == master){
     //a[ARR_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
     // q = 4;
  }

  hypercube(3,rank,a);


  return 0;
}
```

Is there anything that I am not taking care of??

Answer (score 1):

Your array is declared as `int X[]`, so the buffer you have to pass to `MPI_Send()` or `MPI_Recv()` is `X` instead of `&X`.

Note passing `&X[0]` is also correct, though i'd rather suggest `X` because it is simpler.

Comment: I tried sending it with X too. I got the same problem.
I got a work around for this problem but it is not how a code should be. Instead of creating a separate function 'hypercube' I put everything inside main. I dont know why it works now.

Comment: please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and i will have a look.